# How do I provide a list as my parameter in sqlite-net

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-pcl

I am building a Xamarin Forms application and using [Sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). I want to run a delete query that deletes all records that have a field in a list so something like below:

```
//usersToDelete is a list of Objects each representing a user.
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>();
foreach (var user in usersToDelete)
{
    idsToDelete.Add(user.Id);
}
string dbQuery = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id IN (?)";
var deleteCount = await LocalDatabaseConnection.ExecuteAsync(dbQuery, idsToDelete);
```

This does not work for me. It fails with the error Cannot store type: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]`. Does this mean I have build the string in code in palce of "(?)"? Or is there some way to provide this as a parameter.

Comment: I think you need to build the string yourself.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788724/sqlite-bind-list-of-values-to-where-col-in-prm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var utd= usersToDelete.Select(i=> i.Id.ToString()).ToArray();
string ids=string.Join(",",utd);
string dbQuery = $"DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id IN ({ids})";
```

Comment: seems like there's no way to do this just using a parameter, but this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to pass a List or an Array as a parameter into a written SQL query in SQLite-net except using the method in the answer that Serge has given.

This should also work,

```
//usersToDelete is a list of Objects each representing a user.
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>();
foreach (var user in usersToDelete)
{
    idsToDelete.Add(user.Id);
}

var deleteCount = await LocalDatabaseConnection.Table<Users>().DeleteAsync(x => x.idsToDelete.Contains(x.Id));
```

And makes better use of the capabilities of SQLite-net.