# python SQLite3 how to getting records that match a list of values in a column then place that into pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am not experienced with SQL or SQLite3.

I have a list of ids from another table. I want to use the list as a key in my query and get all records based on the list. I want the SQL query to feed directly into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect('c:/path/to/data.sqlite')

# the below values are ones found in "s_id"
id_list = ['C20','C23','C25','C28', ... ,'C83']
# change list to sql string. 
id_sql = ", ".join(str(x) for x in id_list)
df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id in ({id_sql})", cnx)
```

I am getting a DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ... : no such column: C20.
When I saw this error I thought the code just needs a simple switch. So I tried this

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ({id_sql}) in s_id", cnx)
```

it did not work.

So how can I get this to work?

The table is like.

| id | s_id | date | assigned_to | date_complete | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C10 | 1/6/2020 | Jack | 1/8/2020 | None |
| 1 | C20 | 1/10/2020 | Jane | 1/12/2020 | Call back |
| 2 | C23 | 1/11/2020 | Henry | 1/12/2020 | finished |
| n | C83 | rows | of | more | data |
| n+1 | D85 | 9/10/2021 | Jeni | 9/12/2021 | Call back |

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788724/sqlite-bind-list-of-values-to-where-col-in-prm

Comment: @sierra_papa thank you. I did not find this link very helpful. I tried the code `df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id in ('C20', 'C23')", cnx)`. This did return results but concept wise will not work for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are missing the single quotes around your literal values and consequently the SQLite engine assumes you are attempting to query columns. However, avoid concatenation of values altogether but bind them to parameters which pandas [**`pandas.read_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) supports with the `params` argument:

```py
# the below values are ones found in "s_id"
id_list = ['C20','C23','C25','C28', ... ,'C83']

# build equal length string of ? place holders
prm_list = ", ".join("?" for _ in id_list)

# build prepared SQL statement
sql = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id IN ({prm_list})"

# run query, passing parameters and values separately
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=cnx, params=id_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that it is missing single quote marks in the sql string. So for the in part needs **'** on each side of the s_id values.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect('c:/path/to/data.sqlite')

# the below values are ones found in "s_id"
id_list = ['C20','C23','C25','C28', ... ,'C83']
# change list to sql string. 
id_sql = "', '".join(str(x) for x in id_list)
df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_id in ('{id_sql}')", cnx)
```

Comment: Avoid this for parameterization!