# How to toggle sometimes one and sometimes more than one item in Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

```
def toggle_status_of_item(self, item_id: str):
    sql = """UPDATE table
             SET status = CASE status
                          WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 END
             WHERE item_id = ?"""
    self.cur.execute(sql, (item_id,))
    self.con.commit()
```

The above method toggles the boolean value in column `status` of a given `item_id`. However, `item_id` can sometimes be plural, i.e. it may contain more than one value, which I have no control of.

How should I rewrite the sqlite3 doc-string to toggle sometimes one and sometimes more than one `item_id`? Other than changing `item_id: str` to `item_id: list`, how do I write the SQLite commands to apply the `CASE` statement to a list of item ids? Thank you in advance.

Below method will do what I want. However, it is not a pure SQLITE approach. I would like to know the SQL commands to achieve the below.

```
def toggle_status_of_item(self, item_ids: list):
    sql = """UPDATE table
            SET status = CASE status
                         WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 END
            WHERE item_id = ?"""
    for id in item_ids:
        self.cur.execute(sql, (id,))
    self.con.commit()
```

Comment: `item_id` is `str`; if multiple values are expected, how are they delineated (normally I would expect `item_id` instead to be an iterable data structure)? What have you tried so far? Can you show those attempts as a [mre]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering assuming `item_id` uses a comma (`,`) to delineate between distinct `item_ids` for which this query should be run.)

Create a `List[Tuple]` of `item_id`s, then use [`cur.executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany):

```
def toggle_status_of_item(self, item_id: str):
    item_ids = list(map(lambda x: (x,), item_id.split(",")))
    sql = """UPDATE table
             SET status = CASE status
                          WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 END
             WHERE item_id = ?"""
    self.cur.executemany(sql, item_ids)
    self.con.commit()
```

Comment: @python_user No, since each member of `item_ids` has an individual query executed when using `cur.executemany()`.

Comment: @python_user  You could refactor slightly to use `NOT... IN...` and stick with `cur.execute()`, but I believe when using `sqlite3` you'd need to [dynamically add `?` parameters to `sql` for each member of `item_ids`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788724/sqlite-bind-list-of-values-to-where-col-in-prm). Possible, but adds a bit of code complexity that would likely only be desirable at larger scales.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922991/5722359), I learned that:

1. `item_ids` has to be a list of tuples where each tuple contains a `str` element, e.g. `item_ids = [("A",), ("B",), ("C",)]`.
2. I can use sqlite's `.executemany()` to replicate what the python for-loop would do.

Working solution:

```
def toggle_status_of_items(self, item_ids: list):
    sql = """UPDATE table
            SET status = CASE status
                         WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 END
            WHERE item_id = ?"""
    self.cur.executemany(sql, item_ids)
    self.con.commit()
```

and this method can be executed as:

```
item_ids = [("A",), ("B",), ("C",)]
class_instance_name.toggle_status_of_items(item_ids)
```